# php email headers

Tags: php, email

I am having problems changing the 'from' email header in the following script. Everthing else works ok but the from line in the email received is the server name and not admin@mywebsite.com:

```
ini_set("sendmail_from", " admin@mywebsite.com ");

    $adminSendTo = "admin@mywebsite.com";

    $adminSubject = "Contact Form";
    $adminMessage = "Contact Form: $subfirstname $sublastname \r\rEmail: $subemail \r\rSubject of feedback: $subsubject \r\rComments: $subcommentquestion\r\n";
    $adminHeaders = "From: My website Contact Form\r\n";
    $adminHeaders = "Reply-To: admin@mywebsite.com";

    mail($adminSendTo, $adminSubject, $adminMessage, $adminHeaders);
```

Do I need to change settings in the php.ini file for this to work?

Comment: You *must* provide a [valid mailbox](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.2) in the *From* field. What you are using is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't provide any *"From"* field.

By writing:

```
$adminHeaders = "From: My website Contact Form\r\n";
$adminHeaders = "Reply-To: admin@mywebsite.com";
```

you assign the *"From..."* value to `$adminHeaders`, then overwrite just on the next line by a new value *"Reply-To..."*.

Instead, you should write:

```
$adminHeaders = "From: My website Contact Form\r\n";
$adminHeaders .= "Reply-To: admin@mywebsite.com";
```

Here, *"Reply-To..."* will be concatenated to the actual value of `$adminHeaders`, instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Of course! I'm sure I made the same mistake previously. Thanks for he help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$adminHeaders = "From: My website Contact Form <contact@your-contact-site.com>\r\n";
$adminHeaders .= "Reply-To: admin@mywebsite.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You clobbered the data!

Use .= to concatenate the strings together.

If you use "$var = some_value;" twice then only the second occurrence will count.